# Styling a tree containing multiple types based on view model data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, styling

I have a tree containing several different types of items.  I have got as far as having separate viewmodels for each type and the items appearing in my tree.  I have an overall TreeView.ItemContainerStyle which does the basics of binding IsSelected and IsExpanded and also sets the selected item to bold.

I'm now trying to work out how for my different types (each has its own HeirarchicalDataTemplate), how i can style the text depending on data from the associated ViewModel.

To try and explain better here is the basics of my Tree, which basically has a hierarchy of Programme | Task | Budget:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <!--  This Style binds a TreeViewItem to a TreeViewItemViewModel.  -->
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type applayer:ProgrammeTreeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\Programme.png" / -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Programme.ProgrammeName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type applayer:TaskTreeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\Task.png" / -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Task.Description}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type applayer:BudgetSummaryTreeViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\Budget.png" / -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Budget.Description}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

Now what i'm trying to do for example is:
For the Programme item, if the ProgrammeTreeViewModel IsStarted property is true, set the text to green, if IsLate is true set the text to red (in precedence over the IsStarted being green).

However, completely separately for a Task if the TaskTreeViewModel PeopleAssigned property is true set the text to green or if its false set it to red.

Similarly i want to use different attributes of the Budget ViewModel to style up the buget entries.

All of this whilst maintaining the overall bolding up if selected.

I'm sure i'm close and i'm sure this should be relatively easy - i've just been experimenting with the  within each of the HeirarchicalDataTemplates, but so far no joy.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: check the microsoft styling for a tree view and tree-view item: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/treeview-styles-and-templates

Comment: Use DataTrigger ?

Comment: Have you tried applying the different styles inside each HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Comment: As Andrew says, you can apply styles, triggers and formatting within each HierarchicalDataTemplate. You can also set the ItemContainerStyle property, which sets the style for all children of the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aybe stated in the question comments, just use a trigger for this.

It would look something like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type applayer:ProgrammeTreeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!--Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\Programme.png" / -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="myText" Text="{Binding Programme.ProgrammeName}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsStarted}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="myText" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLate}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="myText" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

If both `IsStarted` and `IsLate` are true, then both will execute. The Setter for `IsStarted` will be applied first, then the setter for `IsLate`. This is important to bear in mind because if you are applying multiple setters in a preceding trigger, you will get a mixed result. To manage this you would likely utilise a `MultiDataTrigger`.

Comment: This worked like a charm - thanks to you all for your answers